# Unable to start service from BroadcastReceiver in the background

Tags: android

I am facing an issue while trying to start a service from a BroadcastReceiver in the background of my Android app. The error I'm encountering is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.arunkavale.test.CallReceiver: android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.arunkavale.test/.CallBackgroundService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{b662afa u0a438 RCVR idle change:idle|uncached|procstate|procadj procs:0 seq(2847242,2847240)} caps=------
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4905)
```

**Problem**

I have a BroadcastReceiver (CallReceiver) that is triggered in response to some events, and I'm trying to start a background service (CallBackgroundService) from this receiver. However, it seems that starting services directly from a receiver in the background is restricted, and I'm getting the BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.

```
// CallReceiver.java
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Error occurs when trying to start the background service here
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, CallBackgroundService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}

// CallBackgroundService.java
public class CallBackgroundService extends Service {
    // ... (service implementation)
}
```

1. How can I resolve the BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException when
   trying to start a service from a BroadcastReceiver in the
   background?
2. Are there alternative approaches to start a background service from
   a BroadcastReceiver in the background without violating restrictions
   introduced in Android 8.0 (Oreo)?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no *simple magic* solution. You are trying to `startService`, means to start *background service*, which is not running at that moment - and that, as you stated, is restricted.

Basically you have the following options:

1. The service needs to be bound to something (an Activity or another Service), which is *running* at that moment. [Bound services overview](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/bound-services)
2. You need to start the request as *foreground service*, means with a notification etc. [Foreground services](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services)
3. Start your Application or Activity (binding the required Service) from the BroadcastReceiver (to fill the number 1. option) and startService from there. [Broadcasts limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)